# GWT Mvp and handlers

Tags: java, gwt, mvp, gwt-mvp

I've been learning GWT the past couple months and found out that the Mvp is one of the best ways to design your project. I've read google's tutorial [MVP part 1](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html)
and in their tutorial they put the clickHandlers ( for example) in the presenter.
Now I had problems with that when constructing many view class that has many buttons with the same HTML id, and then the user interacts with these buttons... so if I have one button for every view, total 6 button. and the user clicks on one of them, the button will work 6 times for the same object...
So I read and found out that it is better to put the handlers on the view class and create an event to the presenter.

So that what I did :

View Class :

```
         rb0.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                selectHandler.onEvent(1);
                System.out.print("rate 1");
            }
        });
         rb1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    selectHandler.onEvent(2);
                    System.out.print("rate 2");
                }
            });

         rb1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    selectHandler.onEvent(3);
                    System.out.print("rate 3");
                }
            });

         rb1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    selectHandler.onEvent(4);
                    System.out.print("rate 4");
                }
            });

         rb1.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    selectHandler.onEvent(5);
                    System.out.print("rate 5");
                }
            });
```

Presenter class : (event handler)

```
    private void bind() {
        .
        .
        .

         DoEvent selectHandler = new DoEvent(){
              public void onEvent(int select) {
                  fetchRating(select, user.getUserId());

              }
          };    
          display.setSelectHandler(selectHandler);
```

The call for the Presenter with it's view, it is called from the MainPagePresenter class  :

```
        presenter = new AssetViewPresenter(rpcService,eventBus,new  AssetView(),result.get(i));
```

now my problem is that when I click the buttons from the view nothing happens... like the presenter and the view are not connected, what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a stupid bug... my button are rb0, rb1 ,rb2 ... and I copied the click handlers with the same button id !!! YUP I'm ashamed of myself